# Programmatically changing tabs in a Monotouch app

Tags: xamarin.ios, uitabbarcontroller

Forgive me for my ignorance, as I'm new to Monotouch and I'm sure this is a simple thing but I can't find the answer anywhere.

I have an iPhone app in Monotouch that uses a UITabBarController for root navigation. It is defined in it's own class file. There is also a separate view controller class file for the content of each tab. So tab1 shows viewcontroller1, tab2 shows viewcontroller2, etc.

I want a user to be able to click on button1 inside of viewcontroller1 and have the app take them to tab2 and show viewcontroller2.

I have an event handled for the click of button1 and I can do things like pop up alerts when it's clicked, but I can't figure out how to get the tab bar to be accessible for me to call it. Please help!

Edit: I need to know not only how to make it accessible, but I also don't know what method to call to make it change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your "child" view controllers, pass in a reference to the "parent" tab controller.  Then you child can call a method on it's parent to update the current tab index.

Answer (score 1):

something like

```
btn1.TouchUpInside += (sender, args) => TabBarController.SelectedIndex = 0 ;
```